# Calculate $11^{35} \pmod{71}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Calculate $11^{35} \pmod{71}$

I have:
$= (11^5)^7 \pmod{71}$
$=23^7 \pmod{71}$

And I'm not really sure what to do from this point..

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Fermat's little theorem (and the fact that quadratic polynomials have at most two roots mod a prime), you can conclude that $11^{35} \equiv \pm 1\mod 71$. [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) can narrow this down to the correct answer of -1, but if you haven't yet studied quadratic reciprocity the very useful technique of [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) offers a more low-brow approach to computing this exponent.

Modulo 71 we have

$$\begin{align*}
11^1 &\equiv 11\\
11^2 &\equiv 50\\
11^4 &\equiv (50)^2 \equiv 15\\
11^8 &\equiv (15)^2 \equiv 12\\
11^{16} &\equiv (12)^2 \equiv 2\\
11^{32} &\equiv 4.
\end{align*}$$

That's as many powers of $11$ as we need: 
$$11^{35} \equiv 11^{32}11^2 11^1 \equiv 4\cdot 50 \cdot 11 \equiv 70 \mod 71$$

Answer (score 6):

Using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem):

$11^{70}=(11^{35})^2\equiv 1 \mod(71)$,

so, we only need to find elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{71}$ that square to 1.  Since 71 is a prime, $\mathbb{Z}_{71}$ is a field, so the only elements that square to 1 are 1 and -1.  We can knock out the possibility of $11^{35}\equiv 1 \mod(71)$ by using [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E35+mod+71), please.

Comment: Sorry, edit made.

Comment: How do you go from this to 70?

Comment: How do I go from what to 70?  The only reason that 70 shows up is due to the statement of Fermat's Little Theorem:  $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod(p)$ if $p$ is prime and $gcd(a,p)=1$.  In this particular case, $p=71$ is a prime.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $11^{4} \equiv 15 \bmod 71$ (taken from user7530 above), then:

$$ 11^{35} \equiv (-60)^{35} \equiv -(4 \cdot 15)^{35} \equiv -(2^2 \cdot 11^4)^{35} \equiv -(2 \cdot 11^2)^{70} \equiv -1 \bmod 71 $$